# How can you use Stack Overflow (and its sister sites) to advance your career?

Tags: discussion, jobs, self-promotion

Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault have been growing like crazy - and in my very humble opinion, they have become some of the best sites to ask technology related questions and get prompt, germane, and often correct answers.

In fact, there is a large body of quasi-professional answerers on each of these sites who almost make a profession of responding to peoples' posts. I suspect that ego, visibility, gratification, and the reputation/badge system play a significant role in that. Which, of course is good for everyone.

SO also has features like the CV system and flair that offer opportunities for developers and system administrators to promote themselves and their expertise online.

**My question is:** *in addition* to CV and flair, what are some ways of leveraging your reputation or exposure on SO/SU/SF to promote your career? Actual success stories would be interesting as well.

Comment: Read here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30910/how-do-you-increase-your-stackoverflow-reputation-in-a-realistic-manner

Answer (score 3):

I think that when word gets out, the Career site would be your best bet.

Until then, on your real/paper CV, don't be an *rse and sound like an idiot saying I have xxxx reputation on SO/SU/SF as it makes you sound weird! But by all means write something along the lines of:

"I help out fellow programmers / IT Pros on a community driven website".

You should also bring it up in interview at any possible moment as it shows that you have both knowledge and good at helping others etc.

I had an interview with someone recently and brought it up, they showed some interest in to it as my experience refers exactly to the job that they wanted - However they changed the terms at the last moment and I turned them down.... but I think that adding a link/information in my CV and talking about it was what swung me the job.