# How do you get enough rep to have privileges on sites like this?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you increase your Stack Overflow reputation in a realistic manner?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30910/how-do-you-increase-your-stack-overflow-reputation-in-a-realistic-manner)

How do you get enough rep to have privileges on sites like this?

Aren't most of the questions that can be asked here already asked? How can somebody who hasnt been here since the beginning ever get to a higher privilege level here?

Comment: Try your hand at answering some questions. Also to note, there are plenty of new technologies coming out where very few questions have been asked, but they are slowly gaining popularity. Asking questions/answering question in those areas will help alot too.

Comment: Congratulations, +3 on this question has earned you [a bunch of privileges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges).

Comment: Awesome! lol I guess thats one way

Comment: Or... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast?lq=1

Comment: SockPuppets is when someone has multiple accounts voting for each other (or just one of the), or a bunch of people just voting for each other without regard to quality.

Comment: Your original question referred to having 1 rep, so is this question specifically about meta.stackoverflow, or about Stack Exchange sites in general? I see you have 40+ on Stack overflow...

Comment: @JohnnyD The (now removed) comment was a bit tongue-in-cheek. Not a serious suggestion for you to actually sockpuppet. ;)

Comment: @meta.michael it was intended for meta sites

Comment: While the question this is a dupe of is about SO, it applies to pretty much *any* Stack Exchange site.  And on all of the sites *except* SO, your meta rep is a reflection of your main site rep.